# Extact date from string "3d02h"

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I'm extracting a string from a SSH connection output, which gives me a string like '3d02h' and I have to insert this date into a database.

The output is from the command "show spanning-tree detail | inc ieee|occurr|from|is exec" executed in a cisco_switch, which gave me the following output:

VLAN0001 is executing the ieee compatible Spanning Tree protocol
Number of topology changes 490 last change occurred 3d02h ago
from GigabitEthernet1/0/11

So I used .split() function to extract the '3d02h' from the output.

Now I want to convert the string into a datetime object.

I've tried to use datetime.strptime(string, "%d %H") to extract the day and the hour from the string but it doesn't work.

Comment: You forgot the letters in the pattern. Try `%dd%Hh`

Comment: But that's not a date, it's a time period.

Comment: `"%d %H"` That pattern has a space between the numbers, which your source string does not have.  Also, your source string has the letter `d` after the day, which your pattern does not have.

Comment: The number of days is probably optional, if the time period is less than 1 day.

Comment: I'm trying to convert the '3d02h' ago into a datetime object indicating the day in the calendar it has occurred (like datetime(2019, 09, 1, 23, 55, 59))

Comment: @BrunoTissi: ***"day in the calendar it has occurred"***: Is this the **begin** or **end** date of the period? Read about [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it with re and parsedatetime.

```
from datetime import datetime
import parsedatetime as pdt
import re
cal = pdt.Calendar()
print(datetime.now())
date = "3d02h"
index = 2
date = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+|\d+', date)
date_len = int(len(date))
date_len = date_len // 2
for item in range(0, date_len):
    date.insert(index, ' ago ')
    index += 3
date = "".join(date)
print(date)
date, flags = cal.parseDT(date)
assert flags
print(date)
```

The output is:

```
2019-09-05 13:37:28.710065
3d ago 02h ago 
2019-09-02 11:37:28
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Date ago from a period

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import re

dayshour = "3d02h"
now = datetime.strptime('2019-09-05 13:37:28.710065', 
                        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

days, hours, _ = re.split(r'[dh]', dayshour)

ago = now - timedelta(days=int(days), hours=int(hours))

print('now:{}\n{} => {}, {}\nago:{}'\
      .format(now, dayshour, int(days), int(hours), 
              ago.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> now:2019-09-05 13:37:28.710065
> 3d02h => 3, 2
> ago:2019-09-02 11:37:28
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.6***